# Problem displaying a webgrid in MVC pertial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I already a have a view. Now I have to add a new web grid in that view.
To do this, I have create a partial view and trying to bind a webgrid in the partial with no success. :(

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult RegisteredUsers()
    {
        var query = from p in dc.UserProfile
                    select new RegisterModel()
                    {
                        UserName = p.Name
                    };

        List<RegisterModel> users = query.ToList();

        return View(users);
    }
```

This is my partial view:

```
<%
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model,rowsPerPage:5);
    %>
    <%: 
       grid.GetHtml(
                    tableStyle: "wGrid",
                    headerStyle: "wGridHeader",
                    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                    footerStyle: "wGridFooter",
                    columns: grid.Columns(

                    grid.Column("UserName","User name")

                  )
               )
    %>
```

BUT, it shows an error in the webgrid in my partial view. the error is :
**A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed.**

The error is self explanatory. But the 'Model' in the line "var grid = new WebGrid(Model,rowsPerPage:5);" is the datasource. Isn't it??
Guys any idea how to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in the aspx way but using Razor at the top of the partial view you have to declare something like this `@model <namespace of model>.<modelname>` since you are passing a list then you'd need `@model IEnumerable<namespace of model>.RegisterModel`.

Comment: yes i have that one. <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<MyProjectMvc.Models.RegisterModel>>" %>

Comment: id say make sure you're passing the model to your view from your controller, if that doesn't work perhaps trying 'source:' in front of your model ... id say post the whole view and partial view to get a better glimpse of what could be the issue